# Multi-winding transformers benefits? (DC/DC converter applications)

Tags: transformer, dc-dc-converter, saturation

I've observed that many isolated DC/DC converters use multi-winding transformers and I started wondering why engineers go for this option.

So, apart from having multiple isolated outputs or outputs with different voltage levels:

- What are the benefits of using multi-winding transformers in isolated DC/DC converters?
- Does it make interleaving easier?
- Does it have something to do with reducing the transformer's size/weight?

*EDIT based on the comments I got:*

Not considering auxilary windings but the ones which contribute to power transfer.

To explain my point further, here are a few examples. Theoretically, we can design DC/DC converters which can support high voltage without having to connect low-voltage ones in series. We can also design converters which support higher current without having to connect low-current ones in parallel. All this to say that we should normally get away with a 2-winding transformer.

[image: Examples]

Comment: What do you mean by multi-winding transformer, specifically? Do you mean ones with an auxiliary winding? Or do you mean ones with many windings often connected in parallel or series?

Comment: Benefits with respect to what? I feel the benefits of not having to repeat all the control, switch and feedback circuitry would be too obvious, do you have other aspects in mind..?

Comment: @Hearth, Not the auxilary windings but the ones which contribute in the power transfer. Like you said, often are in series or parallel via some semiconductors.

Comment: @TimWilliams Why not using 2-winding transformer with more powerful semiconductors then? It's let components, less windings, 1 control loop etc

Comment: What can semiconductors do to create additional voltages, especially isolated ones?

Comment: Well, you can't connect transformers secondaries together since you can't guarantee how they'll behave. So you add diodes/transistors between them. This is just an example but you got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, multiwinding generally complicates the design and assembly of the transformer, as you need to have more effecs into considerations in your calculations (especially isolation issues), and there are more wires coming out of your winding, which always make you lose some space in the winding window and make it more difficult to wind the remaining turns.

That said, it also has some benefits:

- You use only one core, which saves costs, as the core hast not a negligible price.
- You share the same primary, which saves you cost and losses, although you have to design to withstand more power.
- It allows you to make a more complex interleaving, which can give you less losses that if they were in two different magnetics (though increasing the manufacturing cost, as I said)
- Some designs actually allows you to cancel out magnetic flux in some parts of the core by winding different secondaries in different columns, reducing the total losses. Take a look at "Matrix Tranformers".
- It allows you to have tapped secondaries, which can help the rectification of the waveform in the secondary.
- It is always more compact than having two separate components

Comment: Commenting on your 1st, 2nd and 6th bullet points, I would argue that that using a 2-winding tranformer would be more beneficial than multi-windings one. Would you agree to that? The other points sound more logical in the high power DC/DC converter applications context. Thank you

Comment: Well, it really depends on the case. On a basic example, without getting into cost, where you don't care about the magnetzing inductance of the transformer, as long as it is large, it could be argued that by putting many windings in one core instead of separated cores, you are "paying" the core losses once, instead of several times.
It can also be argued that more windings in the same winding window could increase the winding losses due to proximity effect, unless complex interleaving is used.
It really depends a lot of the application, the physical constraints, and the budget.

Comment: No no, I think there is a misunderstanding between us. I'm not discussing replacing multiple transformers with a single multi-winding one. Rather replacing a multi-winding transformer with a 2-winding one (Like I said in my question, we don't need multiple secondaries). That why I disagreed with you on those 3 bullet points.

Comment: My bad, I assumed that you if you were moving from multi winding to two windings it was because you were separating them into several transformers, and my points were aimed at that assumption

Comment: No worries. I think you can always edit your answer to adapt to the scenario we've just discussed. Thank you Alfonso for your answer though.